# How to set x axis and y axis to be same in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a straight (diagonal) line from the following simple file.

```
0.1 0.1
0.5 0.5
1   1
2   2
10  10
```

Here is my gnuplot code it doesn't scale the axis proportionately.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set title "w^2 vs 1/m" font ",22"
set xlabel "1/m" font ",15"
set ylabel "w^2" font ",15"
set xtics font ",15"
set ytics font ",15"
set key right top Left reverse spacing 3 font ",15"
set grid
set term png size 1200, 800
set output "w2_repM_e.png"
plot "../data/w2_repM_e" using 1:xticlabels(2) title "w^2" with linespoints ps 4 pt 1
```

Here is my graph
[image]

How to make it look like a straight line?

Thanks

Comment: @ Bibrak … Re: your triangular mesh Q that was deleted: Further searches should include the term tessalations. Some r plotting routines will simulate a surface with triangular segments which can be individually colored.

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks for following up. Yes, I deleted the question since I felt that heatmap as they are in matlaplot is not the right discuss for such a plot. I am thinking of putting the data in square grids then smoothing out to not feel like a square or triangle. Let me check out the tessalations that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

This line fixes

```
plot "../data/w2_repM_e" using 1:2 title "w^2" with linespoints ps 4 pt 1
```